# Big-O for While loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have this algorithm, and I am trying to calculate its complexity.

```
A = {a_1, a_2, a_3, ...}
w = 0
while A != empty
   a' = argmin(A)  #a' is the element with smallest y_a
   if (N_a' + w > C)
      A = A - {a'}
   else
      x_a' = x_a' + 1
      w = w + N_a'
      Update the y_a' value in A using x_a'
```

`A` is a set, and if the condition (`N_a' + w > C`) is *true*, we remove an element from the set until the set is empty. I know that the algorithm runs at least `O(n)`, but it can run more if the `if` statement is *false*. Assume the last line (the update) takes a constant time.

How can I calculate the complexity here?

Comment: Even when you always choose the then case the effort is more than O(n) because of the `min(A)`  and the shrinking of A operations. They will typically take O(log n). Without more information nothing can be said about the else case. If you are unlucky and else is taken each time you have an infinite loop.

Comment: It can't be an infinite loop because of the value of `C`. At some point the loop will terminate when we reach `C`.

Comment: unless N_a' is zero or negative ;-)

Comment: `N_a'` is a positive integer.

Comment: There are still a couple of open points, but if I guess correctly, the algorithm will first increase `w` a couple of times (at most `C` times) and then remove all the elements from the set. (Btw. why are you doing this removal at the end? Couldn't the algorithm just stop once the condition is true?). So it depends on the data structure you chose for the priority queue. A min-heap will give you a run-time of O(n log n).

Comment: The algorithm is underspecified. What is N_a'? What does "Update the values in A" mean?

Comment: @Henry Each element in the set `A` associated with a value `N_a`. Once we know an element's value (`N_a`) will make the condition `N_a' + w > C` _false_, we remove it from the set. I am using the `while` loop because some elements have small value of `N_a` so we can add it to `w` several times. I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @PaulHankin `N_a'` is just a positive integer associated with each element in `A`. The `Update...` will update some values for each element in the set `A`, and `a' = argmin(A)` will find an element with a minimum value that was updated in the last line.

Comment: Without the details it's impossible to specify the running time, or even if the algorithm terminates at all.

Comment: Two additional questions: (1) the `argmin` finds the element with the smallest `N_a'` value or some other minimum? (2) can the `N_a'` values become smaller during an update?

Comment: @Henry (1) `N_a'` is fixed for each element in `A`. The `argmin` finds the smallest value of other minimum, say `y_a`. `y_a` is the one updated in the last line with new value of `x_a`. (2) No, `N_a'` is fixed value. I added `y_a` and `x_a` to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first determine how often the then and else branches can run in the worst case. In the then branch the set A becomes smaller by one element so it can only be executed n times (where n is the initial number of elements in A). The else branch can be executed at most C times (take N_a' = 1, it must be >= 1). C is a constant so this is O(1). The total number of iterations is therefore O(n).

The critical point is now the data structure used for A. Three operations have to be supported: finding the min, removing the minimum element, and the update in the last line. When we choose a min-heap, each of these operations can be done in O(log n). Note that the update is **not** O(1) time in this case. The total run time is now O(n log n).

A naive minimum search (i.e. using an uordered array for A) makes the operations min, remove element, and update O(n), O(1), and O(1) respectively. The total run time would therefore be O(n*n).

Using an ordered array to represent A we get run times of O(1), O(1), and O(n) respectively for our three operations. The min search O(1) operation is executed for each iteration, so O(n) times. The remove elemnt O(1) operation is in the then branch, so executed O(n) times, the update O(n) operation is in the else branch, so executed O(1) times. Taking all together gives a runtime of O(n).
However, if the set has to be sorted in the beginning we are again at O(n log n).

Comment: Very clear analysis and explanation, but I will come back to discuss it with you.

Comment: Can you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375304/big-o-of-while-loop-with-nested-if