# Big-O of while loop with nested-if

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, nested-if

I have this algorithm, and I am trying to calculate its complexity.

```
A = {{B_1}, {B_2}, {B_3}, ..., {B_n}}
t_n = 0   //for every set in A
while A != empty
   Calculate f(t_n) for each element in A using t_n. 
   n' = argmin(A)  //n' is the element (set) in A with smallest f(t_n)
   t_n' = t_n' + 1
   if (t_n' == Constant)
       B_n' = B_n' - {k}     //k is an element in B_n'
       if(B_n' == empty)
           A = A - {B_n'}
```

`A` is a set, and if the condition `(t_n' == Constant)` *and* `if(B_n' == empty)` are *true*, we remove an element (set) from the set `A` until `A` is empty. Assume calculating `f(t_n)` takes a constant time.

If every element (set) in `A` has the same size, can we say that the complexity is `O(|A|*|B_n|)`? How about if elements (sets) in `A` have different sizes?

Comment: It is not clear what `Constant` is. For instance, if `Constant` is too high, the loop will never remove anything and will iterate for ever.

Comment: In my case, `Constant = 6`. So, it's a small number.